# AngularJS: routing to new page not working

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-ui-router

I have a problem routing with angularJS.

When I try to access a new page on button click, the page says Cannot POST /pagename and a console error  POST http://localhost:4200/pagename 404 (Not Found)

I have created a routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NewComponent } from './new.component';

const routes: Routes = \[
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', component: AppComponent },
{ path: 'newcomponent', component: NewComponent}
\]

@NgModule({
imports: \[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)\],
exports: \[RouterModule\]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts imports it:

```
imports: \[
BrowserModule,
NgbModule,
AppRoutingModule
\],
```

in the app.component.ts I made goToComponent():

```
goToComponent(){
this.router.navigate(\['/newcomponent'\]);
}
```

and called it in app.component.html:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="goToComponent()" \>Login\</button\>
```

The problem happens when I press the button. The URL changes from localhost:4200/login to localhost:4200/newcomponent but the page doesn't show the newComponent html, it just shows

```
Cannot POST /newcomponent
```

and a console error:
POST http://localhost:4200/newcomponent 404 (Not Found)

How can I make the button click display the new page?

Comment: restart the server, maybe itll fix it, if possible replicate the issue in a stackblitz and share!

Comment: Restart didn't work. I'm using stackblitz for the first time and it's loading for a pretty long time, I'll share it when I see that it replicates the problem.

Comment: This is not AngularJS - this is Angular. They are siblings but are completely different. I updated the tag

Comment: Sorry for the wrong name. I'm not sure what happened, but the problem just fixed itself somehow. I haven't changed anything but it just started working. Sadly I cannot add a fix to this problem since nothing really happened.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened, but the problem just fixed itself somehow. I haven't changed anything but it just started working. Sadly I cannot add a fix to this problem since nothing really happened.